# enqueueUniqueWork does not compile

Tags: android, kotlin

I using `WorkManager` but `enqueueUniqueWork` does not compile

My code:

```
val oneTimeWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(RemindWorker::class.java)
        .addTag("english_vocabulary_remind")
        .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueueUniqueWork(RemindService.uniqueWorkName, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, oneTimeWorkRequest)
```

I got a error:

> following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
>   @NonNull public open fun enqueueUniqueWork(@NonNull p0: String,
>   @NonNull p1: ExistingWorkPolicy, @NonNull p2: OneTimeWorkRequest):
>   Operation defined in androidx.work.WorkManager @NonNull public
>   abstract fun enqueueUniqueWork(@NonNull p0: String, @NonNull p1:
>   ExistingWorkPolicy, @NonNull p2: (Mutable)List):
>   Operation defined in androidx.work.WorkManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` instead of `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP`